# MLton SML compiler failing build in Bascinet

Tags: ubuntu, sml, mlton

I am trying to set up a workspace for a class, and the professor is mostly familiar with windows systems. I really prefer to do my developing in a Linux environment. I am currently running a x32 bit Lubuntu installation. I have downloaded the latest version of MLton and installed it using Alien. So far my research has not turned much up as solutions for this error.

> "/usr/bin/mlton" "-mlb-path-var" "TL /home/brasmussen/Applications/TL_System" "-mlb-path-var" "DOMAIN /home/brasmussen/Applications/PNF_Students" "-output" "/home/brasmussen/Applications/PNF_Students/Transformation/bin/parser" "-verbose" "1" "-const" "Exn.keepHistory false" "-profile" "no" "-profile-branch" "false" "-profile-stack" "false" "-profile-val" "false" "/home/brasmussen/Applications/TL_System/Parse/parser.mlb"
>
> MLton 20130715 (built Tue Jul 16 16:14:58 EDT 2013 on shadowvm01)
>
> MLton starting
>
> Compile SML starting
>
> pre codegen starting
>
> Error: /home/brasmussen/Applications/TL_System/Engine/ParserGenerator/auxiliary/bit-vector-set.sml 4.5.
>
> Variable all in signature but not in structure.
>
> pre codegen raised in 2.67 + 1.06 (28% GC)
>
> pre codegen raised: Fail
>
> Compile SML raised in 2.67 + 1.06 (28% GC)
>
> Compile SML raised: Fail
>
> MLton raised in 2.67 + 1.06 (28% GC)
>
> MLton raised: Fail
>
> compilation aborted: elaborate reported errors
>   [1] (0m 4s)
>   BUILD FAILED (Mon Jan 30 21:47:41 CST 2017)

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the sources of [TL_System](http://faculty.ist.unomaha.edu/winter/ShiftLab/TL_web/TL_index.html), The error message given appears to coincide with the line:

```
   include ORD_SET
```

There appear to have been a few variations of the [ORD_SET](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/ord-set.html) signature
[a second variation](https://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2015/spring/22620-1/ord-set-sig.html) contains an **all** function, the signature in the mlton smlnj-lib appears to coincide with the latter

while the code and struct portion of BitVectorSetFn conforms to the signature of the former.  While i'm not familiar with the code in question, basing it upon the pre-existing **exists** function, a likely candidate implementation of **all** might be.

```
fun all f s = List.all f (listItemsU s)
```

*Alternately*: an older version of the compiler perhaps, I could not find when exactly this was added.

Comment: A third option might be replacing the include ORD_SET in the sig with the older signature the code conforms to.